# ImportError regarding AppKit module in Psychopy

Tags: python-2.7, appkit, pyobjc, psychopy

I recently downloaded PyObjC to my Mac OS X El Capitan version 10.11.3, so that I could import the AppKit module in PsychoPy. When I attempted to run my script though I received the following error:

```
ImportError: The 'packaging' package is required; normally this is bundled with this 
package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
```

I had read online that downgrading setuptools to version 19.2 will help, so I did that but am still running into the same error in PsychoPy. Is there some other way to address this error or am I doing something wrong?

Edit:
Here is the complete error message that I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dustin/Desktop/CMNT/CMNT.psychopy.py", line 8, in <module>
    from AppKit import NSScreen
  File "/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/AppKit/__init__.py", 
line 8, in <module>
import objc
  File     "/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/objc/__init__.py",     line 32, in <module>
from objc._bridgesupport import *
  File         "/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/objc/
_bridgesupport.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "pkg_resources/__init__.pyc", line 75, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources/extern/__init__.pyc", line 60, in load_module
ImportError: The 'packaging' package is required; normally this is bundled with this 
package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
```

Comment: Also, I'm using Python2.7, if that affects anything.

Comment: Could you paste the import lines and the line number of the ImportError into your question? (press "edit")